# AutoCompleteTextView : Alert if no match found

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

**WHAT I HAVE :**
An AutocompleteTextView *txt_itemName* attached to an array adapter to show suggestions while typing.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> autoCompAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(HomePageActivity.this,        
R.layout.listrow_item_autocomp, items_list);

txt_itemName.setAdapter(autoCompAdapter);
```

**WHAT I NEED TO KNOW**

While typing, if there is no match found, it should inform the user, thru the autoCompleteTextView itself or by some other way

Any suggestions ??